# PHP 7 - stristr() - Show which symbols matched

Tags: php, ajax, function, php-7

I'm working on a MySql search system and everything works just fine, but I saw on some website (not sure which one it was), that there were bold symbols which matched my search, I searched php's website but nothig good, can someone help?

Comment: As per [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), stristr returns string starting with needle and until the end, or, if you provide the third argument, from the beginning and until the needle. In both cases it is trivial to extract the matched symbols because you know how long the needle is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str_replace` for this

```
<?php
$result = str_replace($searchQuery, "<b>$searchQuery</b>", $result);
```

Comment: Actually using a styling class for this would be the better approach, but the general direction is correct.

Comment: Well I thought about something like that, but if for xample I'll have some characters twice in the result but only once in search? Won't it result-in bugs? Btw thank you for your help anyway

Comment: It will only highlight them in bold. Not sure what bugs you are referring to.